# Save response data into variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How can I save all response data into variable in JMeter?
I'm trying to use BSF PostProcessor to get response, but I don't know function to get response.

I want to make something like:

```
vars.put("myResponse", getResponse());
```

Response data like that:

```
{"album_id":873,"total":3}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's what you can do in Beanshell:

```
response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
vars.put("variableName", response);
```

Comment: what does the prev variable do?

Comment: @RCBian - It must get the previous SamplerResult object